# Computation of Factorial in C results in a wrong answer

Tags: c, factorial

I was trying to solve a question on codechef. The question is as follows:

I have to find factorial of number n (1<=n<=100). The specific question is [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2/).

I have written following code to solve it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int ar[160],m,temp,temp1,t,x,i,j;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    int n[t];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
        scanf("%d",&n[i]);
    for(j=0;j<t;j++)
    {
        temp1=n[j];
        if(n[j]==100)
        {
            ar[0]=0;
            ar[1]=0;
            ar[2]=1;
            m=3;
        }
        else if(n[j]<100&&n[j]>=10)
        {
            ar[0]=temp1%10;
            ar[1]=temp/10;
            m=2;
        }
        else if(n[j]<10)
        {
            ar[0]=temp1%10;
            m=1;
        }
        n[j]=n[j]-1;
        while(n[j]>=1)
        {
            temp=0;
            for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                x=ar[i]*n[j]+temp;
                ar[i]=x%10;
                temp=x/10;
            }
            while(temp>0)
            {
                m=m+1;
                ar[m-1]=temp%10;
                temp=temp/10;
            }
            n[j]=n[j]-1;
        }
        for(i=m-1;i>=0;i--)
            printf("%d",ar[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the wrong answer on evaluation. However my code run fine on Ideone.com and gcc on my machine. After going through the code many times I cannot determine my mistake? I will be really grateful if you guys can point out any of the mistake.

Comment: What is this supposed to be: `int n[t];`?

Comment: 32-bit unsigned integers can hold factorials up to 12! while 64-bit unsigned integers can hold factorials up to 20! and 128-bit unsigned integers can hold factorials up to 34!  Reaching 100! will require big-number arithmetic — or at least 525-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @HotLicks: `int n[t];` is a perfectly good C99 or C11 VLA (variable length array).  What did you think it was?

Comment: s/temp/temp1 on line 23

Comment: @HotLicks sorry for no comments. I Will make sure that I comment on every code I write here after.

Comment: @Jonathan yes, thats why I'm trying to store the 100! answer in an array ar [160]. The number of digits in 100! is 158.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this:

```
gcc -o a a.c
echo 100 $(seq 1 100) | ./a
```

The case n=10 is clearly broken (it produces the output 00), but many other lines look ok.

A quick look at code that parses the input when n=10 shows what looks like a typo: "temp" should be "temp1".

Comment: how is the code broken for 10?

ar [0]=temp1% 10 //equal to 0
ar [1]=temp1/10 //equal to 1

the code looks okay.

Comment: @imox that's not what the code says. The mistake (temp instead of temp1) is given in my answer.

Comment: That's correct that was a typo.I didn't intend it like that.anyways I will submit it again with correction and will let you know if it worked. Thank you for noticing.